# Parse JSON from socket

Tags: java, json

How to load JSON from socket and parse values of elements ?

Comment: GSon for parsing part. http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Java tutorial on [Reading from a Socket](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html).

You can then use a JSON parser such as [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to convert the JSON string to a Java object.

Answer (score 2):

Reading from a socket is a kind of basic java

About JSON, if you need performance I recommend you to take a look to Jackson ( http://jackson.codehaus.org/ ) as it's one of the fastest implementation available
(see at http://code.google.com/p/thrift-protobuf-compare/wiki/Benchmarking )

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [REST Assured](http://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/). It makes it very easy to parse json data using [JsonPath](http://rest-assured.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.1.7/apidocs/com/jayway/restassured/path/json/JsonPath.html).